# Text shadow opacity

Tags: opacity, css

Is it possible to adjust the opacity of just the text shadow, rather than the text itself as well?

E.g I have purple text with a blue shadow. I'd like to make the blue shadow have an opacity without losing anything on the purple.

```
h1.blue {text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #3f6ba9;}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes, but specify color in rgba mode to add alpha transparency.

```
h1.blue {text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px rgba(63,107,169, 0.5)} //half of transparency
```

Answer (score 5):

To add on the answer for anyone looking to use HEX code instead of RGB:

```
h1.blue {text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #3f6ba980;}
```

The last 2 characters in the above HEX code has opacity set at 50%. For other opacity values, please refer to opacity-hex charts as linked [here](https://davidwalsh.name/hex-opacity). Alternatively, if you are using VScode, you will be able to use their in-built color picker to adjust the opacity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the shadow *more* opaque, then you can add multiple repeat shadows.  For example, this puts a fairly solid white halo round the text...

```
text-shadow:  0px 0px 2px white,0px 0px 2px white,0px 0px 2px white;
```

I use this shadow style to ensure floating black text is legible even when it floats over other black or dark content.