# CSS text-shadow opcity

Tags: html, text, opacity, css

I'm using part CSS for my practice website and I want to add a shadow to my text, but I want to change the opacity on the shadow, this is the code I'm working with.

Thanks in advance.

```
#text{ text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px #FF9D00; text-family: Gulim; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; }
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549757/text-shadow-opacity

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use rgba instead of hex. The last parameter is the alpha value.

```
#text {
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px rgba(255, 157, 0, 0.5);
  font-family: Gulim;
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-style: italic; 
}
```

Also, `text-family` isn't a valid property. It's `font-family` (fixed above).