# CSS Text Shadow Opacity

Tags: html, css

I have some text with the following css:

```
.text-description-header {
    font-size: 250%;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
}
```

As you can see, it has a black shadow.

**Question**

Is it possible to make the shadow opaque?

Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked before -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549757/text-shadow-opacity

Comment: Instead of black use `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` - the last number is the opacity.

Comment: i also recomment rgba color combination for better color effect ,especially for semi transparent colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the color in RGBA (Red,Green,Blue,Alpha)

Where Alpha is the opacity (0 - 1)

Something like:

```
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

For half transparent black shadow.

Comment: ***Specify the color in RGBA (Red,Blue,Gree,Alpha)***  Need correction, Red Green Blue Alpha

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekPandey

Answer (score 1):

> Use of rgba(0,0,0,0.2); or hsla(0,0%,0%,0.2)

```
 .text-description-header {
        font-size: 250%;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Comment: Tank you that works

Comment: you are welcome!